# How to recover table data, if database crash in Android

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

In android we created a table as "ReportTable", after some month app database get crashed with the **error**:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk
>   image is malformed

After issue when I checked the database all the tables are there with their corresponding values. The error is only coming if we try to read or writer data on "ReportTable". This table is still present in the database with No data.

Is there any thing so we can recover this table data?

Comment: remove table and create it again?

Comment: But how to recover Old data persist in table?

Comment: that depends on how exactly it was corrupted. Which bytes have been corrupted, and how exactly. I don't know how to do it in case of general corruption.

Comment: If it were possible to do this automatically, the software would already do it. Anyway, just restore it from the latest backup.